# Unity - Using Event Manager type class for decoupling

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events, observer-pattern, decoupling

I've been trying to use events to decouple components wherever possible, and recently started reading more about "Event Manager" classes. The implementations I've been seeing however are solving one problem about decoupling but creating another. Let me give an example of some code I found online and my questions about it.

In this example an event is fired (using a static EventManager class) when coins are collected, and we have a producer of the event and a subscriber to it. The producer code:

```
public class Producer : MonoBehaviour {
  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    EventManager.TriggerEvent("collectCoins", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "amount", 1 } });
  }
}
```

And the consumer/subscriber:

```
public class Consumer : MonoBehaviour {
  private int coins;

  void OnEnable() {
    EventManager.StartListening("collectCoins", OnCollectCoins);
  }

  void OnDisable() {
    EventManager.StopListening("collectCoins", OnCollectCoins);
  }
  
  void OnCollectCoins(Dictionary<string, object> message) {
    var amount = (int) message["amount"];
    coins += amount;
  }
}
```

Now let's say the consumer of the event is a UIManager which is a top level class quite specific to the individual game where we're not too worried about reusability. This will work fine and the dependency on the EventManager class probably isn't a big deal.

However for the producer of the event, if it's a "Collectable" class that I've written then I'd like that to be as independant as possible and be able to pop that in to another project without rewriting it. But I can't. Any project I bring the class to now needs a static EventManager class with the same method & parameters or it won't work.

If we look at the more vanilla style of setting up events without an EventManager I would usually do something like this:

```
public class Producer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action<int> OnCoinsCollected;
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        OnCoinsCollected?.Invoke(1);
    }
}
```

Here we have a class that can be transported to another project very easily with no rework required.

When I first read about EventManagers, I assumed the purpose was for the EventManager to handle the subscribe/unsubscribe logic AND to trigger the event, meaning that both the producer and consumer don't know anything about each other and don't know anything about the EventManager. In my mind this is true separation and what decoupling is all about.

Would appreciate some advice on this. To put it in the form of a question - assuming an EventManager class is the best way to approach this problem, how should I build an EventManager class that can handle the invoking of events as well as the subscription side of things so that the classes beneath it have no knowledge of each other nor the EventManager?

Comment: Anything  relying on strings is prone to error. Imho. So id stick with the more normal conventions.

Comment: `both the producer and consumer don't know anything about each other and don't know anything about the EventManager` ... well they (at least the consumer) needs to know one of them as he needs to subscribe to something ;) The other way round you are referring to would be: Let both your classes expose the event and e.g. an initialization method for subscribing to events ... then let your EventManager know both and basically inject the event into the subscriber via the initialization method ... this way the EventManager needs to be involved in the entire initialization process though

Comment: Or you look into dependency injection ;)

Comment: So yes as you decribed the event manager (or other Xmanager class) in my mind would be the one to hold the logic that connects the producer and consumer. What you suggested about creating subscribe/unsubscribe methods that some higher level manager class would use for stringing everything together sounds like it could be a good step towards cleaner design and more separation. Do you have any examples of articles/videos that talk about this kind of design? Is there a name for this design pattern?

Comment: aren't you describing mediator/event bus pattern?

Comment: Yeah, I believe this would still be considered an instance of the mediator pattern. However, in most implementations the event broadcaster is coupled to the mediator (see Extenject's Signals, Mediatr etc.).

However, if the mediator generated delegates from the event listeners and injected them to the event broadcaster (dependency injection pattern), one could avoid coupling the broadcaster to the mediator.

Answer (score 1):

Two-way decoupling like this can be achieved using dependency injection. A very simple example:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

sealed class EventManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private (Action<Action>, Action<Action>, Action)[] config;

    void Awake() => config = new (Action<Action>, Action<Action>, Action)[]
    {
        (x => Coin.Collected += x, x => Coin.Collected -= x, Inventory.Instance.AddCoin)
    };

    void OnEnable()
    {
        foreach((var add, _, var listener) in config)
        {
            add(listener);
        }
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        foreach((_, var remove, var listener) in config)
        {
            remove(listener);
        }
    }
}
```

One possible approach to building such an event manager would be by creating an EditorWindow that allows linking arbitrary events to arbitrary methods using popups, and then have your event manager bind them together at runtime (perhaps with the help of a DI framework).

You could also use convention based binding. For example, you could automatically bind all methods using the naming convention "On{Type}{Name}" to static events named "{Name}" found on types named "{Type}" if their parameter lists are identical. A simple example:

```
sealed class EventManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    readonly List<(Action<Action>, Action<Action>, Action)> config = new List<(Action<Action>, Action<Action>, Action)>();

    void Awake() => BindStaticEventsToMethodsFollowingOnTypeMethodNamingConvention();

    private void BindStaticEventsToMethodsFollowingOnTypeMethodNamingConvention()
    {
        var types = GetType().Assembly.GetTypes();
        var events = types.SelectMany(t => t.GetEvents(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public));
        var listenerNamesToEvents = new Dictionary<string, EventInfo>(events.Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, EventInfo>("On" + e.DeclaringType.Name + e.Name, e)));
        foreach(var method in types.SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods()))
        {
            if(listenerNamesToEvents.TryGetValue(method.Name, out EventInfo eventInfo))
            {
                foreach(var instance in FindObjectsOfType(method.DeclaringType))
                {
                    var listenerComponent = instance;
                    var listenerMethod = method;
                    config.Add((x => eventInfo.AddEventHandler(null, x), x => eventInfo.RemoveEventHandler(null, x), () => listenerMethod.Invoke(listenerComponent, null)));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        foreach((var add, _, var listener) in config)
        {
            add(listener);
        }
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        foreach((_, var remove, var listener) in config)
        {
            remove(listener);
        }
    }
}
```